# Preventing a particular attribute's inheritance in subclass?

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance

If I have the following :

```
class A:
    attrs = [...]
    A_attr = [...]

class B(A):
    B_attr = [...]
```

Is there a way to prevent my `B` subclass from inheriting the `A_attr` from the `A` class?

Or would this be considered a bad design and I should better subclass both `A` and `B` from a third `C` class containing all the `attrs` attributes and add the particular attribute to each subclass like this?

```
class C:
    attrs = [...]

class A(C):
    A_attr = [...]

class B(C):
    B_attr = [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Better idea is to dump the common functionality in a class.

```
class Commmon:
    attrs = [...]
```

Extend this class who want this extra functonality.

```
class A(Common):
    # only one attribute added in this class
    A_attr = [...]

classB(Common):
    attrs_B = [...]
```

Extend class `A` when that extra attribute is needed in the class, this will bring all those other attributes.

```
class C(A):
    attrs_C = [...]
```

What this will allow is wherever you want an object of type `Common` you can provide instance of `B` as well as `C`. And wherever you want instance of class `A` you can provide instance of `C`. *If you add specific instance in each of your subclasses you will not be able to do so.*

*From Comment*

> So according to you I should use the second solution I exposed in my question.

**No**.

Instead of adding the attribute in each subclass, my advice is to add the attribute in a separate class and let your new classes inherit this intermediate class. So you do not have to add the specific attribute in each one of those subclass.

Example is already provided above. Lets see what is the benefit of doing this, as opposed to your suggestion. Take the following function

```
def foo(obj):
    # check to make sure object has the specific attribute
    if (isinstance(obj, A)):
        pass; #do something
    else:
        raise TypeError("Object is not an instance of A")
```

But if we add the specific attribute in each class, the method will need to be changed to something like this:

```
def foo(obj):
    # check to make sure object has the those type which has that specific attribute
    if( isinstance(obj, class1) or (isinstance(obj, class2) or ...):
        pass; #do something
    else:
        raise TypeError("Object does not have specific attribute")
```

Of course, you can perform a check using something like this:

```
def foo(obj):
    # check to make sure obj has attribute
    if hasattr(obj, 'property')
        pass; # do something
    else:
        raise TypeError("Object does not have necessary attribute")
```

*Using correct inheritance relationship (as shown in 1st example) will also help your IDE (if you are using one) in inferring types, because IDE can determine which type of object it expects.* You can even augment the function with type information like this:

```
def foo(obj : A):
    pass; #do something
```

That `A` after colon is a hint to the IDE that function expects an object of type or subtype of `A`.

Comment: So according to you I should use the second solution I exposed in my question? But is the first point of my question technically possible?
I didn't understand why you add a C class though, and I didn't understand your last sentence either, sorry.